# Determining algorithm with many of the inputs and outputs of such algorithm

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have a large amount of inputs and outputs of algorithm and I can't seem to determine what it is. Is there any way I could crack it with the intense power of computing? Does anyone have tips for identifying different ciphers and algorithms. It isn't a hashing algorithm, I am sure of that. The first layer seems to be encoded in Base64, but the second in some strange way. It includes all keyboard characters when in text form as far as I am aware.

Sorry for the vague and nonapplicable question. I'm running out of ideas.
Can I use machine learning with a big list of inputs and outputs?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  Do you want to identify the algorithm?  Or do you want to crack ciphertext produced by it?

Comment: one of the design criteria of modern ciphers is: the output shall be indistinguishable from random bits ... so in short: by just looking at the inputs and outputs, without knowledge of the key, you will not be able to identify the algorithm ... so if you can get your hands on the thing that produces the output, reverse engeneer that ...

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **cryptography** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). However, this is probably too vague to get anything better than vague answers even there.